# need some regex help javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am hoping that someone can help me, I am using Javascript and asp

I have this string /folder1/folder2/pagename.asp

I need a regex to strip the /pagename.asp from the string

```
pagetype.replace(/\/.*?\.asp/ig, '');
```

The regex above is halfway there but the problem is that it strippes from the beginning / everything between the / and the .asp

how do I make the regex lazy so that it will only strip between the last / and the .asp?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: FYI - You may want to get a copy of RegexBuddy: http://www.regexbuddy.com/  It converts your regex into plain English and helps you build new expressions by showing you your options and their meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
pagetype.replace(/\/[^\/]*\.asp/ig, '');
```

I've used `[^\/]` group to represent any symbol not equal to `/`.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(.*)\/.*?\.asp/ig
```

The problem is that the regex is matching as *early* as possible - one solution is to put a greedy quantifier at the start so that it gobbles up all the possible early matches and you get the last one.

And we use a capturing group to grab that bit so we can keep it around.

Answer (score 1):

Sure use this, will strip off the page name and extension:

```
(\w+)(\.\w+)(:[0-9]+)?(/.+)?
```